# How to update email from Firebase in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using this code:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

But still I am not able to update user Email ID for logged in person. Other things working fine but not this.

Comment: Any logcats or errors after executing the code?

Comment: No there is no error

Comment: But other things like register, login, send email verification working fine only this one is not working

Comment: Obviously,  U must be logged in then updating operations as u know. : `Important: To set a user's email address, the user must have signed in recently` Check if you have signed in or not then updating operations ...

Comment: Yes i signed in... m 100%sure becoz i able to send verification email to my logged in email.. only change password and change email not working

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to re-authenticate your user. As according to documentation changing primary email address is a sensitive action.

Re-Authentication :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        // Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication
        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234"); // Current Login Credentials \\
        // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
        user.reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
                        //Now change your email address \\
                        //----------------Code for Changing Email Address----------\\
                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        //----------------------------------------------------------\\
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Ohk Rahul sir, thanx for your ans i know how to get current user email id  but how i get password also? I know with the help of getEmail() i able to get email id but what about password?

Comment: You have to store user login credentials while they login using Shared Preference which is an easy way, or create a dialog in which user enters their credentials and then you pass those credentials to my code.

Comment: Thanx Rahul Sir its working.. but how i able to store password in shared Preference? i mean to say i know how to save data in Shared Preference but how to save password?

Comment: Just retrieve the password from your EditText during login process and just save it, it is same as saving email but with different tag. If my answer helped you then please accept it so it would be easy for others to find it.

Comment: Ohk Rahul Sir Its accepted.. and your ans is very helpful thanx a lot

Comment: So you saved your password via shared pref?

Comment: Yes m doing that now wait 5 mins but simply i able to save password in Shared Preference? Like email id?

Comment: I am asking that are you able to save login credentials in Shared Preference? If you need I can add code for Shared Preference!

Comment: Email is saving find but not password :(

Comment: Great...Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin

```
 // need to sign user in immediately before updating the email 
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("currentEmail","currentPassword")
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success now update email                
                    auth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(newEmail)
                        .addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
               // email update completed
           }else{
               // email update failed
                    }
       }
       } else {
                    // sign in failed
                }
            }
```